# setTimeout usage issues

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript and I am having issues within using `setTimeout`, ie:

```
function setUrl()
{
  // Get system URL details
  var url_path = new String(window.location.pathname);

  var new_url;

  new_url = window.location.host;
  }
  setTimeout("setValue('ONE_UP_URL',new_url);",2000);
}
```

But for some reason, I am getting the error: 'new_url' is undefined.

How can I call this function using setTimeout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a string as the first argument of the `setTimeout` function call, use an anonymous function.

You also had an extra curly brace:

```
function setUrl() {
  // Get system URL details
  var url_path = window.location.pathname,
      new_url = window.location.host;

  setTimeout(function () {
    setValue('ONE_UP_URL',new_url);
  }, 2000);
}
```

If you use a string, it will evaluated and that is not really [recommended](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#evil).

Evaluating code by using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/eval) (and its relatives, [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/Function), [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout), and [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval)) is considered dangerous, because they will execute the code you pass with the privileges of the caller, and almost all the times there is a workaround to avoid them.

Other minor things:

- The call to the String constructor in your code is redundant, since `window.location.pathname` is already a string.
- You can declare your function variables on a [single var](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#var) statement.

Answer (score 6):

You have a rogue closing brace.  Either there is more code missing, or you just need to remove it.  (The line above setTimeout.)

Also, you should replace this:

```
setTimeout("setValue('ONE_UP_URL',new_url);",2000);
```

with this:

```
setTimeout(function() { setValue('ONE_UP_URL', new_url); }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating it to something like:

```
function setValue( s, variable ) {
    alert( s );
    alert( variable );
}

function setUrl()
{
  // Get system URL details
  var url_path = window.location.pathname, 
      new_url = window.location.host;

  setTimeout(
    function() {
        setValue('ONE_UP_URL',new_url);
    }, 2000 );
}
```

Comment: This is the third copy of the correct answer. Shouldn't you delete this?

Comment: You honestly haven't seen duplicate answers on SO before? And in my solution I actually took the time to write the setValue function to demonstrate, in addition to cleaning up more of the code.

Comment: how is multiple declarations on a single line *clearer*? You actually reduced readability.

Comment: When CP initially responded it was two var statements, I just forgot a `\n` - give me a break ;)