# setTimeout issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, settimeout

The menu system is supposed to expand and collapse according to a given delay using the following statements (`o_item.getprop('hide_delay')` returns 200 and `o_item.getprop('expd_delay')` returns 0):

```
this.o_showtimer = setTimeout('A_MENUS['+ this.n_id +'].expand(' + n_id + ');',
  o_item.getprop('expd_delay'));
```

and

```
this.o_hidetimer = setTimeout('A_MENUS['+ this.n_id +'].collapse();',
  o_item.getprop('hide_delay'));
```

I tried placing the code for the first argument into separate functions and call these functions as the first argument to setTimeout like this:

```
this.o_showtimer = setTimeout( expandItem(this.n_id, n_id),
      o_item.getprop('expd_delay'));
```

Firebug produced the following error message:

```
useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)
```

And there was no delay in the collapse.

I placed the argument in quotes (though recommended against [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598634/settimeout-usage-issues/1598643#1598643)) like this:

```
this.o_showtimer = setTimeout( "expandItem(this.n_id, n_id)",
  o_item.getprop('expd_delay'));
```

but this didn't work.  It appeared that nothing was happening at all and throwing some console.log() messages into the code confirmed this.

I tried using an anonymous function call as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598634/settimeout-usage-issues) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267239/settimeout-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-in-firefox) like this:

```
this.o_showtimer = setTimeout( function() { expandItem(this.n_id, n_id); },
  o_item.getprop('expd_delay'));
```

but this didn't work either.  It produced undesirable results in IE (items not collapsing is the same manner as before) and nothing happening in Firefox (placing console.log() statements in expandItem and collapseItem functions confirmed that they weren't being called).

I even tried doing the following:

```
this.o_hidetimer = setTimeout( function() { alert('test'); },
  o_item.getprop('hide_delay'));
```

and that didn't even work!  Seems there's something up with calling the anonymous function.

Discovered that assigning the value of setTimeout to a variable *other* than this.o_showtimer made the left argument of setTimeout fire.  Must be something to do with assigning something to this.

If I do this:

```
var o_showtimer = setTimeout( function() { expandItem(this.n_id, n_id); },
  o_item.getprop('expd_delay'));
```

expandItem gets called.  However, if I do this:

```
var o_showtimer = setTimeout( function() { expandItem(this.n_id, n_id); },
  o_item.getprop('expd_delay'));

 this.o_showtimer = o_showtimer;
```

As if setTimeout can predict the future! (expd_delay is 0!).

Comment: I suspect `o_item.getprop('hide_delay')` is not integer, so try this: `this.o_hidetimer = setTimeout( function() { alert('test'); }, parseInt(o_item.getprop('hide_delay'), 10));`

Comment: It sounds like someone is later coming along and doing `clearTimeout(this.o_showtimer)`.

Comment: Quick test (http://jsfiddle.net/hkH9n/) shows it's not global problem with functions - please show us the code around the `this.o_showtimer = ` and we'll see.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. @Jason, your comment made me investigate further and, through the use of firebug, I discovered what the problem was. There was an abundance of mouse events coming through which must have been overriding the ones I wanted since the functions that handle the events reset the timers.  I managed to zero in on the problem and changed a line of code (too much to detail here).  I'm not exactly sure now why it was doing the thing it was doing but changing that line solved my problem. Essentially, I had to "new" the menu as opposed to just calling it as a function.

Comment: Kudos to you guys for your comments.  I voted them up as they helped me :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is in Javascript's idiosyncratic treatment of 'this'. When you call 'expandItem' within your anonymous function, you are not calling it as a method, so 'this' gets set to the fundamental scope (window).

I would suggest using a local variable

```
var that = this;
this.o_showtimer = setTimeout( function() { expandItem(that.n_id, n_id); },
  o_item.getprop('expd_delay'));
```

Comment: Tried that but no joy.  I didn't think that was the problem as, like I said, the expandItem function isn't being called in the first place.  Thanks for trying anyway.  Appreciate it.